# Query Refactor without union

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Can we re-factor below query without using union.
May be we can use or logical operator in where condition.

```
select a.RequestNumber, a.ticket_id as TicketID, a.requester,   num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, sysdate) as businessdays,a.REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS from (SELECT ticket_id, request_number as  RequestNumber, created_by as requester,
  last_modified_date,REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS

      From Ri_Ticket_Info
      Where Status_Id = 6 And REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS   Is Null)A
      where num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, sysdate) >= 5

      union

      select a.RequestNumber, a.ticket_id as TicketID, a.requester,   num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, sysdate) as businessdays,a.REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS from (SELECT ticket_id, request_number as  RequestNumber, created_by as requester, 
      last_modified_date,REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS

      From Ri_Ticket_Info
      Where Status_Id = 6 And REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS   Is not Null  )A
      where num_business_days (a.REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS, sysdate) >= 5
```

Comment: Can you re-format the code. Very hard to read as it is now.

Comment: I agree with@NoDisplayName that there is no need at all for a UNION in this case, in the future, you might consider that when you have mutually exclusive conditions in both parts of the UNION, a UNION ALL is much faster.  Anytime I write a UNION statement, I consider if UNION ALL might be a btter choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be rewritten as just:

```
SELECT a.requestnumber,
       a.ticket_id AS ticketid,
       a.requester,
       num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, SYSDATE) AS businessdays,
       a.rem_mail_sent_dtts
FROM   ri_ticket_info a
WHERE  a.status_id = 6
and    num_business_days (nvl(a.rem_mail_sent_dtts, a.last_modified_date), SYSDATE) >= 5;
```

Comment: I hope above query works. When rem_mail_sent_dtts is null  function num_business_days first parameter is a.last_modified_date.Otherwise rem_mail_sent_dtts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any logical operator, Remove `REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS` condition from `where` clause

```
SELECT a.RequestNumber,
       a.ticket_id                                       AS TicketID,
       a.requester,
       Num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, sysdate) AS businessdays,
       a.REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS
FROM   (SELECT ticket_id,
               request_number AS RequestNumber,
               created_by     AS requester,
               last_modified_date,
               REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS
        FROM   Ri_Ticket_Info
        WHERE  Status_Id = 6)A
WHERE  Num_business_days (a.last_modified_date, sysdate) >= 5
```

Comment: I think you've missed the case where the `REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS` is not null, the OP wants to filter on `num_business_days (a.REM_MAIL_SENT_DTTS, sysdate) >= 5`